# How to pass data on create from one model to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**I have 3 models:**

`user.rb` with attributes `id`, `name`

`article.rb` with attributes `id`, `title`

Article `belongs_to: user_page`

`user_page.rb` with attributes `user_id`, `article_id`, `read_article`
`has_many: users`
`has_many: articles`

How to pass `read_article:false` for all user when `article` created:
**Example:** There are 32 users in DB. And we create article #1.

Then in the `user_page` table should be created: from `user_id:1 ... user_id:32` with `article_id:1` and `read_article:false`

What should be in the controller, when creating the article?:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  ...
end
```

Comment: Set a default value.

Comment: @japed the question is: what i should add to `def create` so it add/create `user_id` and `article_id` in `user_page`  table for all existed users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find_each` :

```
def create
 @article = Article.create(article_params) # Use create to have @article.id
 UserPage.find_each do |user_page|
  user_page.article_id = @article.id
  user_page.read_article = false
  user_page.save!
 end
end
```

If you use `Article.new` instead of `Article.create` you won't have an `@article.id` to assign to your `UserPage` model. This code assumes you already created a `UserPage` model for each user with an `user_id`.

**UPDATE**

In case you didn't create the UserPage model for each user :

```
def create
 @article = Article.create(article_params) # Use create to have @article.id
 User.find_each do |user|
  UserPage.create(user_id: user.id, article_id: @article.id, read_article: false)
 end
end
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks. In case if i did not created `user_id` for each user, how to create it when i creating article?